# JSF 2.0: Limit value of h:outputtext to a specific number of characters

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using an h:outputText to display a value. I would like to limit the value displayed such that when it's greater than 50 characters in length, it's truncated to 50 characters and an ellipsis is appended to the truncated value. For example:

```
This is some text that has been trun...
```

I know I can achieve this in the backing bean but I was wondering if anyone knew of any tags that can achieve this without adding code to the managed been. Seems like a common use case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Custom JSF Converters as explained in "[JSF for nonbelievers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/#N10239)". [Here's](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200604.mbox/%3CE075E730CFDBAE4B86E86216721A74F279B12A@VS6.EXCHPROD.USA.NET%3E) an example of text truncation converter.

Comment: Thanks. I also found a section in Core Java Server Faces 3rd edition which deals with implementing custom converters and converter tags.

Answer (score 28):

You can use JSF EL.. for example

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.string.length() gt 50 ? bean.string.substring(0,47).concat('...') : bean.string}" />
```

Comment: It's tedious to repeat the same logic over all place where needed. It's then easier to have a single and reuseable converter or even an EL function for that. The JSF utility library OmniFaces has an `of:abbreviate()` function for the very purpose.

Comment: You are right.. but suppose that the case is to crop the string of an attribute like <p:panel header="#{bean.string}">.. In this case, using converters is not the best option.

Comment: That's exactly when an EL function is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've split it up in outputtext tags and used the rendered to define whether or not to substring

Answer (score 7):

As [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874043/jsf-2-0-limit-value-of-houtputtext-to-a-specific-number-of-characters#comment-18669278) mentioned, OmniFace's [of:abbreviate()](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings) could be a good solution for your problem:

```
<p>Abbreviate a long string: #{of:abbreviate(string1, 20)}</p>
```

Comment: Just used this, works great, for reference the namespace import is: xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"

Comment: 0

Only a complement: You need add this at your .xhtml page at ui:composition tag

xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"

And if you dont have an omnifaces library yet, you too needs add it at your pom.xml

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces

bye!